# How to center a hitbox inside rotating triangle sprite?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having problems plotting hitboxes in the center of rotating triangle sprites. When I spawn the triangles, I set the collision rectangle like this:

```
bullet.collisionRect.width = flashingTriangleSprite.getWidth() - 20;
bullet.collisionRect.height = flashingTriangleSprite.getHeight() - 14;
bullet.scale = 0.287f;
```

Updating is done as follows:

```
bullet.position.y += bullet.velocity.y; 

// center collision rect over triangle sprite
bullet.collisionRect.x = 
  bullet.position.x + ((flashingTriangleSprite.getWidth() / 2) - bullet.collisionRect.getWidth() / 2);
bullet.collisionRect.y = 
  bullet.position.y + ((flashingTriangleSprite.getHeight() / 2) - bullet.collisionRect.getHeight() / 2);

if (bullet.scale < 1)
{
  bullet.scale += 0.011f;
}

if (bullet.driftDirection == Globals.Direction.LEFT)
{
  bullet.rotation -= 3.804f;
  bullet.position.x -= bullet.velocity.x;
}
else // drift right
{
  bullet.rotation += 3.804f;
  bullet.position.x += bullet.velocity.x;
}
```

This is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHAzE.jpg

As you can see, the hitboxes are not centered. In fact, the hitboxes seem to change position within the triangle sprites depending on the rotation of the triangle sprite. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining your hitbox centre position you are targeting the centre of the triangle sprite (a square), but that is not the perfect centre of the drawn triangle.

Therefore your hitbox is always closer to one of the vertices of the triangle (depending on the rotation). Also, your hitboxes are never rotated with the triangle, instead they always appear to be standing vertically.

To place the hitbox in the middle of the triangle you should aim for 1/3 of the height of the sprite (if the triangle has one side flat at the bottom in the base sprite image) and when you are updating the sprite, attempt to update the hitbox rotation to match the sprite rotation.

You could also try making a more accurate triangle hitbox using the PolygonShape, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by setting the origin of the sprite, and the y-position of the hit box to 1/3 of the height of the sprite. It's not perfect, but it's a lot more center than it was.